# Renting a flat in San Diego for my son

Tags: usa, accommodation, rental, san-diego

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the easiest way to find a vacation rental?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/733/whats-the-easiest-way-to-find-a-vacation-rental)

My 20 years old son and his friend are going to visit San Diego for a month in August and I'm looking for a place for them to stay.

He said he searched on Google and found some apartments, but in my opinion (I'm not sure about the rent prices there) they are very expensive, about $2,000 a month.

I wonder if there are cheaper alternatives, and how to find them. For example a campus apartment?

(We are from Italy)