# Business Trip Lodging in Manila?

Tags: accommodation, hotels, philippines, manila

I'm in the process of booking a 5-week business trip to the Legaspi area of Makati City in Manila.  Given the length of stay, a standard hotel is not only expensive but also lacks necessities such as kitchen and laundry.

I've been looking around on the internet and have found several apartment/condo listings for weekly or monthly rentals.  (For example, there are 5 listings on TripAdvisor which are exactly where I'm looking, walking distance from Ayala Ave. and Makati Ave.)  However, my concern is that these almost look like Craigslist ads abroad.  So I'm not entirely sure about sending money to such a listing.

Does anybody have any particularly good and reliable resources for finding lodging of this type?  Any other recommendations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to find a vacation rental?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/733/whats-the-easiest-way-to-find-a-vacation-rental)

Comment: @Phoenix See my answer, finding a vacation rental is much easier, because they are much more heavily (and centrally) listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is, in fact, a fully furnished condo with all utilities included available for extremely short term lease. They are rather abundant in Makati city, but they will be advertised in random places.

These are investment properties maintained to fill the exact need that you have, and you will often be doing business with an agent of the owner (broker) who is paid a modest commission for sales and a monthly fee for the upkeep of the property. You're going to be dealing mostly with Craigslist / classified ads unless you happen upon a property that is managed by one of the larger property management companies.

It is not at all unreasonable to ask to pay a reservation fee up front and the remainder of the agreed amount prior to moving in. This protects the seller and you. You should also ask to see recent pictures of the property, and it would not be rude to say something like:

> Would you mind including a dated copy of today's news paper in the photos?

Also make sure that the price includes:

- Electricity without additional deposit(s)
- Cable without additional deposit(s)
- Water without additional deposit(s), working hot water in the shower

You'll know right away if you're dealing with an accredited honest broker or some shady character trying to separate people from their money on The Internet.

Finally, it's rather common (and expected) for the receiving party to pre-arrange these things for you when speaking of business trips. It's *much* better if you can get someone local to do the research and leg work for you.

What I can tell you (because I live in Mandaluyong and work in Makati) is that the properties in the location you stated (walking distance to Ayala / Makati ave) are *very* nice, so your chances of hitting something good are very high.

On a closing note, don't forget to go to Glorietta mall (can't miss it), locate the movie theater and then look for a food shop called Tater's. Try the popcorn.

Comment: Lots of great advice, thanks!  As the date approaches (I'm traveling later this week), my employer and I decided that what I'll do is stay in a nearby hotel for starters and consult with the people in the local office to find a place first-hand.  I've made a number of contacts with people there already, and the common thread across all advice is to find something in-person and judge the character of the agent for myself.  (As you said, I'll know if I'm dealing with an honest broker or a scammer.)

Comment: @David No worries. Make sure you try that popcorn, though. If you see someone walking around Makati wearing an SO t-shirt, it's probably me.

Comment: I've packed my t-shirt too :)  And I'll add that popcorn to my to-do list.